# How to retrieve custom SQL Server Error message information from Hibernate's SQLExceptionHelper in Java Spring Boot w/ JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In my Spring Boot application I have a connection to a Microsoft SQL Server Database. In this database I have a Stored Procedure that throws an error if I cannot validate a parameter.

```
            RAISERROR('Testing error code handling', 10, 2);
            THROW 237820, 'Testing error code handling', 1;
            RETURN 2;
```

SQL Server catches the error and my Spring Boot application receives the error code and error message:
[SQLExceptionHelper Warning and Error from Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEnfQ.png)

But the actual exception that is thrown from the stored procedure is a PersistenceException.

```
@Repository
public interface TestStudentRepository extends JpaRepository<TestStudent, Long> {

    @Procedure
    void addStudent(String displayName) throws PersistenceException;
}
```

I've caught that in another method but the persistence exception does not contain the very helpful information that the SQLExceptionHelper was able to obtain from Microsoft SQL Server.

```
 @Override
    public int addStudentBySPROC(String displayName) throws TestStudentStoredProcedureException {
        try {
            testStudentRepo.addStudent(displayName);

        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            System.out.println("I've caught you!");
            e.getCause();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I would like to know the **error code** (237820) and **error message** (testing error code handling) so that I can handle my custom errors from my SPROCs better, but I have not been able to figure out how to get that information.

Should I just abandon this pursuit of getting the actual error code and instead just return an OUT parameter with the error code in it? That doesn't seem like the most appropriate way of handling this though.

Your insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? Hibernate wraps the original exception, so you just have to unwrap the causes to get to the actual exception. From there on, you can extract all that the JDBC driver gives you.